# Style Different current page menu item for each page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Here's what I am trying to replicate: At brit.co, click on menu item, both text and icon changes from white to black. In WordPress, I can set current-menu-item to ONE icon, so that the ONE icon appears on every active page, but cannot do a *different* icon on each page, as shown at brit.co

The code shown works, but again, the active icon is the same on every page. The "current-page-item" is not respecting the styles I set up for each menu page. I've never seen this done in WP, and maybe can't via CSS alone.

```
#access .menu-style-page-1 a {
background:url('/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/menu-1-white-icon.png') no-repeat 0.5em 0.5em transparent;
padding:0 1.2125em 0 2.2em;
}
#access .menu-style-page-2 a {
background:url('/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/menu-2-white-icon.png') no-repeat 0.5em 0.5em transparent;
padding:0 1.2125em 0 2.2em;
}
/*** current_page_item styles are below ***/
#access .menu-style-page-1 .menu_bar .current_page_item > a, .menu_bar .current-menu-item > a, .menu_bar .current_page_ancestor > a {
background:url('/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/menu-1-black-icon.png') no-repeat 0.5em 0.5em transparent;
padding:0 1.2125em 0 2.2em;
}

#access .menu-style-page-2 .menu_bar .current_page_item > a, .menu_bar .current-menu-item > a, .menu_bar .current_page_ancestor > a {
background:url('/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/menu-2-black-icon.png') no-repeat 0.5em 0.5em transparent;
padding:0 1.2125em 0 2.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without diving into your stuff too directly, this is fairly simple. A standard menu is something like

```
<li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item menu-item-1"><a></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item menu-item-2"><a></a></li>
```

When you click on a link - it all add a class `current-menu-item`

You can do something like this in CSS

```
#menu-item-1.current-menu-item { background: #f00; /*red*/ }
#menu-item-2.current-menu-item { background: #0f0; /*green*/ }
```

Also, within the Appearance > Menu settings, you can click on "screen options" and check the box for "Classes" and then you can add custom classes, so you could do

```
.aboutus.current-menu-item { background: #f00; /*red*/ }
.contactus.current-menu-item { background: #0f0; /*green*/ }
```

You need to add a class to each menu item in Appearance > Menu. And in your CSS, you need to do

```
.your-class.current-menu-item { background-image: icon1.png no-repeat; }
.other-class.current-menu-item { background-image: icon2.png no-repeat; }
```

In the instance above, .current-menu-item alone will NEVER have a background image, ONLY if it has another class involved.

If it IS overwriting, it means you have something like this below:

```
.your-class.current-menu-item { background-image: icon1.png no-repeat; }
.current-menu-item { background-image: BADicon.png no-repeat !important; }
```

This code above will NOT work, because the "CASCADING" style sheet rule for `.current-menu-item` overrides your individual styles above. (and the !important helps it override).

if you remove any instances of the individual `.current-menu-item` and ONLY do `.your-class.current-menu-item` it **will** work.

Comment: Problem is, CSS won't recognize the each class I set up, per page, in Appearance > Menu settings. So, result is, one icon/color for ALL menu items; the curretn-menu-item overrides all items. If I add !important, then the respective icon/color shows on all items. It still overrides.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, menu classes are recognized, but when using *current-menu-item*

Comment: Appending my answer with more info.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks! Cannot find .current-menu-item alone, in the theme's stylesheet, so am unusually stuck here. I don't have any menu plugins that might override the stylesheet. I have added style declarations to two of the four menu items, for testing purposes. Sorry I can't post a URL as am developing on local machine.

Comment: Solved. Will not work with current-menu-item, as subsequent entries override, assume by design, and looks like have to modify php.

Comment: Solved. Will not work with current-menu-item, as subsequent entries override, assume by design, and looks like have to modify php.

Solution is simple: add one style using menu id's, add per-page style using page id's, thus:

    li#menu-item-26 a {background:url('whiteicon.png') no-repeat; left-padding: 2em}

    .page-id-2 li#menu-item-26 {background:url('blackicon.png') no-repeat; left-padding: 2em}

Answer (score -1):

Solved. Will not work with current-menu-item, as subsequent entries override, assume by design, and looks like have to modify php.

Solution is simple: add one style using menu id's, add per-page style using page id's, thus:

The menu:
    li#menu-item-26 a {background:url('whiteicon.png') no-repeat; left-padding: 2em}

How the menu displays per-page:
    .page-id-2 li#menu-item-26 {background:url('blackicon.png') no-repeat; left-padding: 2em}